# UIImageView underneath UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimage, uicollectionview

I have a `UICollectionView` with a footer that contains a `UIImageView`. At the moment the image view is right at the bottom of the collection view as you would expect. Obviously this means that the image scrolls with the collection view.

I was wondering how I could 'stick' the `UIImageView` to the bottom of the view so that when you reach the bottom of the `UICollectionView` the image appears underneath the bottom edge?

Hopefully I have explained it clearly enough. I'm sure it's pretty much the reverse of what I have seen people do at the top of views.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Like making it the footer of the collection view?

Answer (score 0):

Basically you want a layout where the `UIImageView` is not a subview of the `UICollectionView`; you want it to be a subview of the `UICollectionView`'s superview.

Another way of saying that is you want the `UIImageView` and the `UICollectionView` to be siblings (next to each other instead of on top/below each other).

When you add the image view as the footer, you are saying the image view is a part (a subview/a child) of the `UICollectionView`.

Say you initialize like this:

```
var layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout();
var collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100), collectionViewLayout: layout)
var imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 100, 100, 20))

self.view.addSubview(collectionView) //collectionView and imageView added to the same subview, next to each other
self.view.addSubview(imageView)
```